# I can not convert result of an ActionResult Method to JsonResult in the return line. I get an error in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I am new to C#, ASP.NET Core, and LINQ. I have been working on an action method to be used with an autocomplete. I am just working on the Razor page C#. I can not replicate many different examples of code returning the `ActionResult` to JSON:

```
public ActionResult SwordSearch(string term)
{ 
    var searchResult = _context.SMReferenceDB
                               .Where(Swordmakers => Swordmakers.LastName.Contains(term))
                               .Select(Swordmakers => Swordmakers.LastName)
                               .ToList();

    return JsonResult(searchResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In Visual Studio, I get this error at `JsonResult`:

> Error CS 1955 Non-invocable member 'JsonResult' cannot be used like a method.

I have tried everything I can, I went to many examples of autocomplete for Razor and MVC and they all use the `JsonResult` or JSON. I have all the references and NuGet packages.  This seemed like a normal way of making sure your result would be return in a JSON format.

I can't build the solution because of this error, I have also copied and pasted examples of code and get the same red underline error in VS.  Thank You for your help. I am perplexed, been working on this one line for hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike some of the other helper methods on a controller for returning ActionResults like `Ok` or `NotFound`, `JsonResult` is a type and not a method. You need to create a new `JsonResult` to return it, like so:

```
return new JsonResult(searchResult);
```

We omit the `JsonRequestBehavior` in asp.net core, as it's been deprecated. You can choose to pass in custom serializer settings here.

You should also be able to call the controller's `Json` method as well.

```
return Json(searchResult);
```

Comment: Thanks I tried your suggestion and it seemed very correct, however I am getting a new error that I have encounter before.

Error CS0104 'JsonResult' is an ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult' and 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'

Comment: I re-pasted your code everything worked except JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet parameter. There I get a The name 'JsonRequestBehavior' does not exist. Still seems like I am missing a using statement. Like I said in my previous comment I put those in and still came up with errors.

Comment: @ljk401 I crossed my wires a bit between asp.net and asp.net core. I've edited in a solution for core.

Comment: It Worked, No Problem,Now I have to figure the rest out :)  Thanks so much, Been out of the programming game for about 5 years. Had my 4th Open Heart and it didn't go as planned. So, I am starting over. Used to be a VB.NET and asp classic legacy programmer. I like C# and Core. It's just very different.  Again Thanks